# How to add interface to check each prop type correctly?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Working with Typescript I am trying to have an interface with each property inside my object of marks. Currently, I am using "any" but this is not the smartest to do. What is the advice to do here? Thanks in advance for the help and tips.

I am sharing my error and code underneath. Trying to become better in TS so would be great for know how I can solve this.

Error:

```
Type '{ highlight: ({ children }: { children: any; }) => Element; buttonLink: ({ text, value }: any) => Element; internalLink: ({ text, value }: any) => Element; link: ({ children, value }: any) => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'marksProps'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'highlight' does not exist in type 'marksProps'.ts(2322)
```

Code:

```
import Link from "next/link";

import { Warning } from "phosphor-react";

interface marksProps {
  children?: any;
}

export const marks: marksProps = {
  highlight: ({ children }) => <mark>{children}</mark>,

  buttonLink: ({ text, value }: any) => {
    const title = value?.colors?.title;
    const path = value?.path;

    /* prettier-ignore */
    const Theme : { [key: string]: any } = {
      neon      : "bg-neon text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite",
      clear     : "bg-transparent text-white border-white hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      bubblegum : "bg-bubblegum text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      sand      : "bg-sand text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      navyBlue  : "bg-navyBlue text-white border-white hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue"
    };

    const Button = () => (
      <>
        {path ? (
          <Link href={value.path}>
            <a
              className={`inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 mt-6 text-xs font-bold text-center uppercase duration-300 ease-in-out border-2 rounded-full ${Theme[title]}`}
            >
              {text}
            </a>
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <div className="block mt-4">
            <p className="flex gap-2 text-sm font-bold text-sand place-items-center">
              <Warning size={24} color="#ffd662" weight="duotone" />
              <span>Page reference URL is required.</span>
            </p>

            <button
              disabled
              className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 mt-3 text-xs font-bold text-center uppercase duration-300 ease-in-out border-2 rounded-full disabled:bg-gray-700 disabled:opacity-30"
            >
              {text}
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );

    return <Button />;
  },

  internalLink: ({ text, value }: any) => {
    return (
      <Link href={value.path}>
        <a className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum">{text}</a>
      </Link>
    );
  },

  link: ({ children, value }: any) => {
    const blank = value.blank;

    return blank ? (
      <a
        className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum"
        href={value.href}
        rel="noreferrer"
        target="_blank"
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    ) : (
      <a
        className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum"
        href={value.href}
        rel="noreferrer"
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `children` property to be an array of `React.ReactNode`.  After that, you also need to assign your type, `marksProps`, to the props of the `marks` arrow function props and not the constant.

```
import React from "react";
import { Warning } from "phosphor-react";

interface marksProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode[];
}

export const marks = {
  highlight: ({ children }: marksProps) => <mark>{children}</mark>,

  buttonLink: ({ text, value }: any) => {
    const title = value?.colors?.title;
    const path = value?.path;

    /* prettier-ignore */
    const Theme : { [key: string]: any } = {
      neon      : "bg-neon text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite",
      clear     : "bg-transparent text-white border-white hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      bubblegum : "bg-bubblegum text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      sand      : "bg-sand text-navyBlue border-navyBlue hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue",
      navyBlue  : "bg-navyBlue text-white border-white hover:bg-offWhite hover:text-navyBlue"
    };

    const Button = () => (
      <>
        {path ? (
          <Link href={value.path}>
            <a
              className={`inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 mt-6 text-xs font-bold text-center uppercase duration-300 ease-in-out border-2 rounded-full ${Theme[title]}`}
            >
              {text}
            </a>
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <div className="block mt-4">
            <p className="flex gap-2 text-sm font-bold text-sand place-items-center">
              <Warning size={24} color="#ffd662" weight="duotone" />
              <span>Page reference URL is required.</span>
            </p>

            <button
              disabled
              className="inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 mt-3 text-xs font-bold text-center uppercase duration-300 ease-in-out border-2 rounded-full disabled:bg-gray-700 disabled:opacity-30"
            >
              {text}
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );

    return <Button />;
  },

  internalLink: ({ text, value }: any) => {
    return (
      <Link href={value.path}>
        <a className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum">{text}</a>
      </Link>
    );
  },

  link: ({ children, value }: any) => {
    const blank = value.blank;

    return blank ? (
      <a
        className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum"
        href={value.href}
        rel="noreferrer"
        target="_blank"
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    ) : (
      <a
        className="underline cursor-pointer text-bubblegum"
        href={value.href}
        rel="noreferrer"
      >
        {children}
      </a>
    );
  },
};
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKABMk0AbFIuTAVwDsNgJ24AZYOwDWACgB0EpgHMAzgC44KdgE8A2gF0AlAqXKKlKqEiw4AbzgB1Ju0FS4AXxY48+MAAsIM99AC0RdDBkVIbsMEhQmOhIcCBMQjIACjhgMmZUcHBobsD01ETsAPwKyAFiJRgAchC0Gvr2wZRIAB7G8Gg8MvCxUPFwALxplBnZUm70wKMwCiLmWTl5SLz2Ct3xSRApmv0AfHAAPKvbpnO5+fZ7APSHADQNGQBGrDAwPALC0+ZhTTDXcABuKHorGiy0UKi2fV2pnSGUyHXgMGAMHo0QGAKBSAKYna9GgMixiORSH0sLh7E6cDAKBgbn6-0BwKxVJp+hhGQuACpKURnsBwj4JuxoNEORc2WSKQAVNxIEDRBTmVRCJDKBSdKC2dQ6FQOOnQoakuDsJA8Q1wBT4e5SHzG01fGA2lB-ZQAIQxcHu0FoUEdzrdwLgHj+4TkVp8EEwmAs2TC+FuBtJDFQUENFrDMCgSi8TEWCOaDoA7jHop6oN6fEWkdEgyGwxGo8XAxBg1A5Pbfa6MXHxQ9WPd7iipKw8GnrY9+4Ph3B2+wnZ2A6Xy7O-e6a6265Ho1Wmy22-mO-6kN2E7CZEpqGbRz4z+wLzO54ePV7+cv59Xm7XrfWt2EdyH7yuwLHmar6PuaBBhqB7rtpWv6LvysHvruG4Ntua57t8B5duK9isie7TkvALpPC8vADCIEK7CIPb7NsNEZKYzK0gUcDUSeZp7G8QiBkQmB9KY6LAmITH2HR7FmvsKD0RJDAoDIMgVCgcr8QABoI4zGj4mAok0cBViAMg+GgubhJSTQ+AALJSyg+AATDEDoAGzTvuTSpJgPAOp6uQuZhxmhKZrBgGA4RoHJ0TUKwmaIjwPgAMwAAwJXAqAyEgArsOGTxPmW-L2TgHC0NQWmsPQ9BwAAJKY0qykgqiEii6j2Cp9TiWaYkSRJpj2q1nWkpcKAdX1lxcUNZpbNM0kZHs1DAH8mSMPJinKZauJoNxIAOhZ+BjcNYALXJClKUgfT4NpzRwFIKBgHZvkOjIeAeaEPjeXe+43heYCMMZAphAZRkmVAO1TYaexWFANjsHYMjAAAXidpi2RZjg4tAp0AMSRtQjmObZ+BwAWSATG4MCnZFECkUecAXLtfX7Nm7DbAkKBSNEvHhIsxlwAAqggfB6akRAAI6sMARDUGIlwM7TEmXGAYkg9NjzPDwiuwrNZ4Dkg1BqxkslLcdp3qYI6Xnbp+mGf5YQpmA5lWWANn2Zt8V3T4bksJ5L0QD57ZW4FwWheFcCRdF3CZYlyWpelghZfA8E+vlECFdrJVlcHwCayi1ChtaUiZjZADsSXp5n2tyBs6BIjZiX4GrMudd1+a9XT+wXMrpH17ClyzX8neaM3-U0+Kmh4aSPJRbwezESrvA0ySDjxjCgjW7O9BcR8d2-IJILasolGDGPSAwBPrE0ZxgjcW4vH8dvwnUm4onSXsKAHQbK3J1AGnRGgUUyL4kDL1Mu2ccWshwgB2o3b45wLiDTPhcUaw9572EXgaDSQgN4nAWOwLeDId5gj3jsA+sICIUgHEobiaJcFiDIcIUesJx4Qw9IwYQcAWJsQ4lJNqr8jrv1vOEL+mRf7-wgIAlMwC+ygOHLXLhV8kB8QElQ2RmAB6GiIPQU6Qp2ZQCIEDaSMBpBH1OgAfRoUIaR7VpLHGyKcRYKjpowN2hNU+4ln7SX1jwk6+AP4CJ-lAP+PoAEBTEfuEBk5wHSSUTfRRvE7H0KQOo-Ami5HhB0eYw0ncrHzDOHA2BJ4R4wmQVQXCQA)